# DELETE not working as expected in Express/Postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, crud

I have created a Kanban board using JS without a framework on the FE. On the backend, I am using Express/Postgres.

My issue is with my 'Delete' operation not working. All other CRUD ops are fine.

When I use the app to try and delete a 'plan', the request returns a status '200' code but the entry does not actually get deleted.

My code is below -

Queries.js

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
 user: 'kanban',
 host: 'localhost',
 database: 'kanbandb',
 password: 'k4nb4n.d3',
 port: 5432
});

const getPlans = (request, response) => {
 pool.query(
  'SELECT * FROM plans ORDER BY project_id ASC',
  (error, results) => {
   if (error) {
    throw error;
   }
   response.status(200).json(results.rows);
  }
 );
};

const getPlanById = (request, response) => {
 const id = parseInt(request.params.id);

 pool.query('SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
   throw error;
  }
  response.status(200).json(results.rows);
 });
};

const createPlan = (request, response) => {
 console.log(request.body);
 const planID = request.body.planID;
 const planName = request.body.planName;
 // const barColor = request.body.barColor;
 const checkbox_state = true;
 pool.query(
  'INSERT INTO plans (plan_id, plan_name, checkbox_state) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)',
  [planID, planName, checkbox_state],
  (error, results) => {
   if (error) {
    throw error;
   }
   console.log(results);
   response.status(201).send(`Plan added with ID: ${results.insertId}`);
  }
 );
};

const updatePlan = (request, response) => {
 //const id = parseInt(request.params.id);
 const { planID, planName, barColor, checkbox_state } = request.body;

 pool.query(
  'UPDATE plans SET plan_name = $1, plan_id = $2 WHERE id = $3',
  [planID, planName, barColor, checkbox_state],
  (error, results) => {
   if (error) {
    throw error;
   }
   response.status(200).send(`Plan modified with ID: ${id}`);
  }
 );
};

const deletePlan = (request, response) => {
 console.log(request.body);
 const planName = request.body.planName;

 pool.query(
  'DELETE FROM plans WHERE plan_name = $1',
  [planName],
  (error, results) => {
   if (error) {
    throw error;
   }
   console.log(results);
   response.status(200).send(`Plan deleted with Name: ${results}`);
  }
 );
};

module.exports = {
 getPlans,
 createPlan,
 updatePlan,
 deletePlan
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
// const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const db = require('./queries');
const port = 3000;
const cors = require('cors');

// var server = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

// override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
// app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
 bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
 })
);

app.options('*', cors()); // include before other routes

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
 response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' });
});

app.get('/plans', db.getPlans);
//app.get("/plans/:id", db.getPlanById);
app.post('/plans', urlencodedParser, db.createPlan);

app.post('/testpost', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
});
app.put('/plans/:id', db.updatePlan);

app.delete('/plans/:planName', urlencodedParser, db.deletePlan);
// console.log(req.body);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

the my server returns this:

```js
Example app listening on port 3000!{}
Result {
  command: 'DELETE',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
} {
  id: '5',
  plan_name: 'hello world',
  plan_id: 'ssss'
}
Result {
  command: 'DELETE',
  rowCount: 0,
  oid: null,
  rows: [],
  fields: [],
  _parsers: [],
  _types: TypeOverrides {
    _types: {
      getTypeParser: [Function: getTypeParser],
      setTypeParser: [Function: setTypeParser],
      arrayParser: [Object]
    },
    text: {},
    binary: {}
  },
  RowCtor: null,
  rowAsArray: false
}
```

If I try the same with Postman, I get :

'Plan deleted with ID: [object Object]'

The error thown on the screen from the request when done in the app is in this screenshot.

[image: error message]

This is what I have in my JS on the front end:

```js
// ************ Delete User ************
function deletePlan(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Pop up a confirmation dialog
  let confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this plan?');

  // Check and make sure the user confirmed
  if (confirmation === true) {
    // If they did, do our delete
    $.ajax({
      type: 'DELETE',
      url: 'http://blusrv019.blue.works:3000/plans/' + planName
    }).done(function(response) {
      // Check for a successful (blank) response
      if (response.msg === '') {} else {
        alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // If they said no to the confirm, do nothing
    return false;
  }
}

// ********* Delete User btn click *********
$('#deletePlanBtn').on('click', deletePlan);
```

I feel like I am missing some thing really stupid but havn't been able to figure it out.

Can anyone provide some wisdom? I have been searching the WWW all day and not found a similar situation or solution and have changed my code around in so many ways that I have lost track.

Any advice is appreciated. Also sorry if my post is not appropriate or structured correct (I'm still a newb).

Comment: As a quick aside, you should really delete via id instead of name (just like how you update via id). I doubt the name is unique across the entire DB, and if it’s not, you’ll delete more records than intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `planName` as part of the body of your `queries.js` file, however in you r `index.js` and front end, you're passing the `planName` as a URL parameter:

```
url: 'http://blusrv019.blue.works:3000/plans/' + planName
```

You should either provide the `planName` in the body of the AJAX request or change the `queries.js` file to use `request.params.planName`.

Comment: Thank you! the 'request.params.planName' did the job. P.s. the planName in the url params was because it's getting the result from a user input.

Thanks again!